# unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new in react-native.
I have run react native project on Ubuntu by using 'react-native run-android' command. And I got the error on emulator 
"Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'.Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you are running a package server."

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: you can find your answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795384/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-make-sure-your-bundle/45409223#45409223

Comment: make sure ADB is install and accessable in your path

Comment: I was facing the same issue and it solves: https://queception.com/question.php?question=10

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59051365/index-android-bundle-not-updating-when-creating-release-build/74854019#74854019

Answer (score 23):

I also got this and I resolved this using following commands in your project directory:

```
$ mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
```

`$ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

```
$ react-native run-android
```

Comment: I tried with React Native version 3.x and changing index.android.js with index.js works.

Comment: which react-native version you talk about. you made it up yourself?

Comment: i have a same issue and this solution does not work for me. it seems that after i added babel-plugin-module-resolver to my project this happens. (if it helps i have react-native-navigation from wix company in my project)

Answer (score 16):

Using
npm version 4.3.0
react-native-cli version 2.01
react-native version 0.49.5

In project directory,

- `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`
- `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
- `react-native run-android`

The file name has changed from **index.android.js** to **index.js**

Comment: This really helped me with react native 0.70.6 was crashing in release mode. spent hours till find this.

Answer (score 10):

In my case (embedding React Native as a new `Activity` into an existing Android Code Base), the problem was Android Studio had auto-imported the wrong **BuildConfig**.

Wrong:
`import com.facebook.react.BuildConfig;`

Right:
`import com.mywebdomain.myapp.BuildConfig;`

This would apply to the wherever you are housing this block of code:

```
mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
        .setApplication(getApplication())
        .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
        .setJSMainModulePath("index")
        .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
        .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
        .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
        .build();
```

Comment: Can I buy you a beer?

Comment: same here...been scratched my head since this morning and this was the issue...

Answer (score 3):

For this error :

> unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'

1) Check for "**assets**" folder at :

```
mkdir android\app\src\main\assets
```

If the folder is not available, create a folder with name  "assets" manually. and execute the Curl command in terminal.

2). Curl command:

```
curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o"android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

It will create the "index.android.bundle" file in assets folder automatically and  resolved the issue.

3) Then:

```
 react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 2):

This  helped me resolve the problem in following steps.

- If not than (in project directory) mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
- `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
- `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 2):

> Ubuntu

first time, I created new app with `react-native init project-name`. I got the same error. so i do the following steps to resolve this in my case.

1. Firstly run `sudo chown user-name-of-pc /dev/kvm` in my case.
2. While debugging from your Android phone, select `Use USB to Transfer photos (PTP)`.
3. Create Folder assets in 'project-name/android/app/src/main'.
4. make sure `index.js` be avaiable into your project `root` directory and then run below command from console after `cd project-name` directory.

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

or for index.android.js then

> react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

5. run command `./studio.sh` in `android-studio/bin` directory. It will opens up Android Studio.
6. run command `react-native run-android`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem in the newest version of React Native (0.46). Using the previous version seems to solve the problem `react-native init name --version react-native@0.45.1` and removes the error when running `react-native run-android`.

Edit: It is now fixed in version 0.46.1.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was in this row in the React Activity file:

```
mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
...
   .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
...
```

BuildConfig.DEBUG must be set to true, while in my case it was false

Answer (score 1):

For Windows user only:

1. Copy the path of adb location and set into `PATH` in your system variable,
2. Open project structure and delete node module folder.
3. Edit your project `package.JSON` file
   change react-native version `"react-native": "0.55.2"`, and
   babel `"babel-preset-react-native": "4"`, after that run `npm install`
4. Restart cmd and js server and run your react native project by `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck in the same problem for hours and what solved my issue is this :
Create "assets" folder in main directory of project as well as in "newreactproject\android\app\src\main". Then put this script in package.json  `"android-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android"`
like:

```
"name": "newreactproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution suggested in the thread at https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15388

It is to manually set the *Debug server host & port for device* setting for the app on the phone.

**Step by Step to eject and run a CRNA on Android**

In terminal:

1. `create-react-native-app myApp`
2. `cd myApp`
3. `yarn run eject` (I used default options "regular React Native project")
4. `react-native run-android`

*(now the app should be compiled and installed on the phone)*

On phone:

5. Run the app (expect to see the red error screen! - click Dismiss button in bottom left)
6. Shake the phone and pick **Dev Settings**
7. Pick **Debug server host & port for device** and set to 192.168.x.x:8081 (make it your actual LAN IP of course)
8. Restart app on phone and you should see green bar at the top "Loading from  192.168.x.x:8081..."
9. You should also see some "Bundling `index.js`" action in the Metro Bundler (that opened when running `react-native run-android`)
10. After the bundle is finished, the app should be running on your Android device!

Live Reload (when source files change) also works - just shake the phone and touch "Enable Live Reload"

You can run the project from Android Studio, but you need to first start the Metro Bundler with the command `react-native start` in the CRNA project root.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too. But `adb reverse`worked for me

Answer (score 0):

i'm using ubuntu 18.04 LTS ,react-native: 0.55.2.  In my case here are few solutions for the problem .

1. in the terminal before you run npm run android type npm start. you might see an error
   ERROR  Metro Bundler can't listen on port 8081.
   this occurs because there might be a process which is already running

   Solution- type `sudo lsof -i :8081`

   you will see an output similar to this

   > **COMMAND  PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
   >
   > ```
   >  node    5670 tasif   17u  IPv6  80997      0t0  TCP *:tproxy (LISTEN)**
   > ```

   type  `kill -9 (PID number)`then `run npm android`.
2. if it still doesnt work type again npm start . you might see this error

   E`RROR  ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch'....../......./.....'`

   solution :

   $ `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288`

   $  `sudo sysctl -p`

   then type  `npm  run android`.

   please go to this link to see different solutions and more details https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details
3. delete the emulator and build it again. kill the recent terminal and then build emulator and start again.