# Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am having working React Native application having version 0.38.0, when i have tried to upgrade it to 0.45.1 it is showing following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server.
at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:198)
at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:33)
at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:216)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:994)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$600(ReactInstanceManager.java:109)
at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$4.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:746)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I have tried following solutions but it didn't work for me

[SO: unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)
[SO: react native android failed to load JS bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572399/react-native-android-failed-to-load-js-bundle)

Comment: I think You should follow this answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44476757/7516620

Comment: I was facing the same issue and this link solves my issue: https://queception.com/question.php?question=10

Answer (score 28):

1- Create a new folder => `android/app/src/main/assets`
2- Run this command =>

```
 react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

This command will create 2 files : `index.android.bundle` & `index.android.bundle.meta`

3- run command => `react-native run-android`

Comment: `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`   ---- For me, I have no **index.android.js**, so change it to **index.js**, this solves my issue. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @LiuWenbin_NO I also needed to alter the solution a little. I actually deployed through Android Studio. It did however work as expected.

Comment: if you don't have `index.android.js` it will automatically consider `index.js`

Answer (score 6):

Add these lines

`project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js",
        bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
        bundleInAlpha: true,
        bundleInBeta: true
]`

before
`apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` in build.gradle

Comment: Thanks god I found your answer. Several days waisted

Answer (score 3):

Okay. Every answers are unique depending on 'when' and 'the version' at the time the problem occur.

> Today is 27 August 2018 ( 1.2 years from this page posted) and I still
>   found the same problem when I install react-native and create projects
>   (on windows) by following the official website instruction.

And honestly it is very difficult to find the right answer to make it work like 'normal' for 'today', because everything has changed and is different from the time that has been left behind.

> Now for the above question : Unable to load script from assets
>   'index.android.bundle'.

Meaning that we don't have the file as requested in the directory assets. That's all the problem!. There is no relation to port, devices, emulator etc.

Now what we need to do is to make the file is 'exist there'. And these are some options to you can do depending on your package configuration :

> Create the directory 'assets' if not exist as requested in directory
>   android/app/src/main/ or you can type in the console : mkdir
>   android/app/src/main/assets

In your project directory, execute :

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

> Then check in the asset folder if the files is already there. If not,
>   then try the second way :

```
1 react-native start // open npm window popup

2 curl "http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"
```

> Then check in the asset folder if the files is already there. If not,
>   then you need to down grade your project to earlier version packages.
>   Follow these 5 steps and must complete one by one :

```
1 npm remove --save react-native
2 npm i --save react-native@0.55.4
3 npm remove babel-preset-react-native
4 npm i --save babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0

5 react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

If you already have the files in asset folder, then you can continue your project.

Check if your device is connected and ready, and run-android :

```
adb devices
```

Make sure you get result like this :

```
List of devices attached
cb8eca15        device
```

Then run :

```
react-native run-android
```

Note : Alternatively, you can create a new project again with a specified version :

react-native init ProjectName --version 0.55.4

Answer (score 2):

To resolve Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle - React Native follow below process :

You have to create dir assets manually in your android project or make Directory by Terminal/CMD enter mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

Go at the created Directory if that is successfully created then

run step 3 Command:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

you have your missed files in the folder now you can Run your React Native project npm run android.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53275340/9489285

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the emulator was on airplane mode.
Make sure your emulator or mobile phone can communicate with the Metro server.