# Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle',Make sure your bundle is packaged

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

I have made sure that bundler and emulator are running.

If I use this commend

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

It might work but refresh won't happen when I press *rr* in emulator.
I have also tried reversal of abd `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.
Nothing works for me.

[click here to see the error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14pMz.png).

Comment: Hi, please check my issue 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45229579/could-not-run-adb-reverse-react-native/48331530#48331530
i hope it works

Comment: hi, i have already tried this but still its not working

Answer (score 3):

To resolve Unable to load script from assets `index.android.bundle` - React Native follow below process :

You have to create dir assets manually in your android project or make Directory by Terminal/CMD enter `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`

Go at the created Directory if that is successfully created then

**run step 3 Command**:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
```

you have your missed files in the folder now you can Run your React Native project npm run android.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to clear the cache to load your assets properly.
Use the command `react-native start --reset-cache`
and re-run `react-native run-android`

Comment: delete your android and ios folders from your project directory and create again using the command **react-native eject** followed by linking your assets using a command **react-native link**

Comment: see this article it will solve your issue https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/solved-unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-bdc5e3a3d5ff

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after having had it work for the past couple days. I realized that I had manually configured a proxy. As soon as I turned that off, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Gradle clean fixed it when I was having an issue on Android

```
cd android

./gradlew clean
```