# index.android.bundle not updating when creating release build

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm working on a Project in ReactNative & it's working fine in debug build (When installing via **react-native run-android** but When I generate a release build it crashes as soon as I open it, according to logs it's unable to load script, and **android/app/src/main/assets** directory is empty.

To resolve **this** I had to run these commands:
`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

`rm -rf ./android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*`

But now the file **index.android.js** won't update in a release build, so I have to run the above commands every time I need a release build, what am I doing wrong?

Here are my packages.json details:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },



"react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.5"
```

***In short:*** How to create or update index.android.bundle automatically when I generate a release build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the procedure first time.

```
mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res 


npm start -- --reset-cache

react-native run-android
```

if you want to take an apk file

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

finally

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Basically The below commands worked for me

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: "Execute the Following code every time when you run your code in physical device." That's the problem, In my other projects I don't need to do this (in debug build as well as release build)

Comment: I added new a few lines

Comment: For react-native versions 0.57 and above the bundle output path should be: `android/app/build/generated/assets/react/debug/index.android.js` See [react-native cli documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/commands.md#--bundle-output-string) for more details.

Comment: oh no this break my app :(
now it won't build

Answer (score 2):

for `react-native 0.70.6`:

make sure you have `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2` in your android/build.gradle and not `com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1`

Comment: I would give this 1 million up votes if I could!  I spent so many days trying to figure out what was wrong. As soon as i downgraded to 7.2.2 my app updated again. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: you are a saviour man!

Answer (score 0):

for integrating with exist app release mode case, here is my solution.

gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
hermesEnabled=true
```

setting.gradle

```
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')//this solved index.android.bundle not built issue.
```

build.gradle(project level)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

build.gradle(app level)

```
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
dependencies {
 ..
 implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" // From node_modules

if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
  implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
} else {
  implementation jscFlavor
}
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

in order to let debug build can be run in same code base. Some code need to be add as below
Create a debug version of AndroidManifest.xml, add

```
<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

in build.gradle(app level), add

```
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
```

Hope this help for solving issues.