# Error: Unable to load script. Make sure you are either running a Metro server or your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release

Tags: java, android, react-native, facebook

I upgraded my React Native project from 0.63.3 to 0.66.4 with the help of this resource
https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.3&to=0.66.4 (followed every instruction in it).

But after generating the apk and I see the below error during the launch ->

```
01-27 19:12:46.364  9223  9895 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
01-27 19:12:46.364  9223  9895 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
01-27 19:12:46.364  9223  9895 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:2)
01-27 19:12:46.364  9223  9895 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:1)
01-27 19:12:46.364  9223  9895 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:3)
01-27 19:12:46.364  9223  9895 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.o.s(ReactInstanceManager.java:39)
01-27 19:12:46.364  9223  9895 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.o.c(ReactInstanceManager.java:1)
01-27 19:12:46.364  9223  9895 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.o$f.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:12)
```

My index.android.bundle is getting generated in the correct path And I tried every possible solution below to resolve this error, but nothing seems to resolve the above error:

- $ mkdir android/app/src/main/assets

  $ react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --
  bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
  android/app/src/main/res
- In Project build.gradle =>

  project.ext.react= [

  bundleInDebug: true,

  bundleInRelease: true ]
- In androidManifest.xml =>

  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

  tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning
- In Project build.gradle =>

  project.ext.react= [

  entryFile: "index.js",

  bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",

  devDisabledInAppDev: true,

  devDisabledInRelease: true ]
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49143330/18210851

**Please suggest some solution.**

Answer (score 0):

Before doing the first step i.e., `mkdir android/app/src/main/assets`, you have to run the metro server using the `npm start` command. The below link has all the steps required to create an offline APk in debug mode.I can see that the first step is missing.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37965603/8988448

Comment: I am running first npm start only.

Comment: Ok. The problem here is pretty much clear. If you see the description of the error "Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start')", it simply states that still, your app is looking to make a call to the metro server to get the javascript( debug apk and release apk should not do this). Could you try to clear the gradle cache and metro cache before running the above steps using below commands? command 1:  cd android && ./gradlew clean 2: npm start --reset-cache.

Comment: Have done it all. build is working fine on local machine. The release apk on bamboo throws this error on app launch

Comment: If it is the release build, i would suggest you the check this link. https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/38#issuecomment-1209353339

Comment: @Swetha., any luck with the above comment? I suspect the issue is with the release build

Comment: Hi, Still no luck. No workaround is helping. The issue persists with release build.

Comment: Ok. I thought the above link would solve the issue. But I have a question here. Are you still running npm start as the first step? I think this step would be needed only if you are building debug apk. But as you are building release one, you should not run that step I believe. This link mentions 4 steps that needs to be followed. https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/38#issuecomment-1209353339.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck on this problem for ages and finally found a way to get it to work. I previously tried the bundling solution with the command to create a bundle inside the assets dir but hot reload didn't seem to work there. The two lines that got this to work:

1. Open a new terminal window, and navigate to your project directory.
2. Use the command:

> ```
> npx react-native start --port=8088
> ```

3. This will start your metro bundler in the said terminal on a different port i.e. 8088 in this case (It starts in port 8081 by default).
4. Open another terminal window, navigate similarly to your root directory.
5. Use the command:

> ```
> npx react-native run-android --port=8088
> ```

Now you can get hot reloads and the app runs as expected!